# Cordova Media Capture captureImage crashes for IOS

Tags: javascript, cordova

this app was working fine and was published on the app store about 3 weeks ago. However, now when I use the Cordova media `captureImage` function it eventually black screens and force quits.

I can actually take a photo, it is only when I click 'use photo' it crashes.

I can record and use videos just fine, which I also find puzzling.

I'm confused why it suddenly stopped working?
Also the same code is used for android and it works fine.

I am having to test by uploading to test flight so I haven't got the choice of USB debugging.

Cordova version:
8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

XCode: Version 10.1 (10B61)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

I have added the appropriate config changes for the permissions.

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
  <string>My Reason..</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription">
  <string>My Reason..</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
  <string>My reason ..</string>
</edit-config>
```

Here is My JavaScript:

```js
function takePicture(filePreview, multiUpload) {
  var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
      path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
      if (filePreview !== null) {
        var image = document.getElementById(filePreview);
        image.src = path;
      }
    }
  };

  // capture error callback
  var captureError = function(error) {
    //alert("oops");
  };

  // start image capture
  if (multiUpload) {
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {
      limit: 5
    });
  } else {
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {
      limit: 1
    });
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might have removed it in your permissions, but check to ensure you still have NSCameraUsageDescription, NSMicrophoneUsageDescription, and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescriptionentry in your info.plist file. It has removed it before for me when I updated my project for some reason.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look now and get back to you

Comment: They are still there - any other ideas?

Comment: Are the descriptions still filled or are the fields empty? Is the plugin version you have up to date? It might be a compatibility issue if your phone is on iOS 12 but the plugin version you have doesn't work for iOS 12

Comment: The descriptions are full, apple made me redo them 5 times haha. The device I am using is currently running iOS 11 - which is the same phone + OS I used 3 weeks ago and it was working

Comment: Okay - have you debugged it at all through Xcode with your device plugged in? It should give you a reason why it crashed. You can also debug it on Safari

Comment: I would just assume it's some sort of permission issue if it works fine on Android and works for capturing video on iOS

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to use USB debugging with the IPhone I have been given to test with (very annoying)! Thank you for your help Kody! I'll look more in to the permissions